# TListView event OnSelectItem holds the wrong TListItem instance?

Tags: lazarus, fpc

The TListItem returned in OnSelectItem event of the TListView holds the previously selected item instead of the latest (current) one. Is It a bug? Tested in Linux Mint 17.2, Lazarus 1.4.4, FPC 2.6.4

Feed a TListView with some items first...

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; Selected: Boolean);
begin
    Form1.Caption := Item.Caption;
end;
```

Comment: Same on Lazarus 1.2.4 in XUbuntu trusty!

Comment: it must be a bug. Turning `MultiSelect=True` **solves** the issue...

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the `selected` parameter. The event gets called multiple times, with the old item and selected=False, and the actual item with Selected=ON.

When coming from Delphi, it happens.